# Doctrine PDO always using transactions with mysql, is it possible to disable it?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Any INSERT/UPDATE query we send using Doctrine/PDO to MYSQL translates to a transaction like follows.

```
START TRANSACTION
UPDATA table1 SET a=1;
COMMIT
```

We tried setting the auto_commit value to true in the [doctrine.yaml](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html) file but that did not work.

How can we disable transactions and use transactions just for some of our queries?

**EDIT:** Sample php code generating the above mysql query:

```
    $table1 = $repo->findOneBy(
        [
            'id' => 1,
        ]
    );

    if ($table1) {
        $table1
            ->setA(1);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

Comment: Whats `use_savepoints: false` do?

Comment: this sounds like you're flushing too often. (`flush`ing wraps all insert/update/deletes currently pending into a transaction, ... okay, depending on change tracking, obviously)

Comment: @Jakumi I added the php code above. There are is just one flush.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I tried use_savepoints: false per your advice. It did not help.

Comment: @Haluk what I'm saying is: there will be one transaction per flush, so if you're calling code - like you've just added - quite often, hence many flushes, there will be many transactions. and as far as I know, you can't flush without a transaction. And on average, using transactions for your changes it what you should want.